# How to set pip3 working for python3.7, not python3.8

Tags: python, pip

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. I'm not an experienced Linux user, therefore I need help in Python configurations.

As far as I understood, the OS comes along with Python 3.8 preinstalled.

I need to work with tensorflow and 3.8 is not a good fit for that.

I installed python 3.7 and made an alias in bashrc for python. Now when I run python in terminal I see that I'm running exactly 3.7.
However, the problems occur with packages installations via pip and pip3.
Pip doesn't work. I obtain the following notification:

```
Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.
```

pip3 only works for 3.8. When I run `pip3 --version`
I obtain:

```
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

What should I do in order to work with Python 3.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `python -m pip ...`.

So, add an alias to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias pip3.7='python3.7 -m pip'
```

or

```
alias pip='python -m pip'
```

Comment: thank you so much! I completely forgot about `python -m`